# By.xpath(contains(text(), "Some text") gives error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

The following code says that "The method text() is undefined for the type Test" and prompts me to create a new function text() in class Test.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(contains(text(), "menu")));
```

I am using Eclipse Kepler and Selenium 2.39.0.

The exception i receive is : `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException`. 
I am not able to figure out where am i going wrong.

Comment: `text()` is presumably a static method in the style of Hamcrest matchers and needs an `import static` if you're going to use it without specifying the class.

Comment: I am a newbie. Where do I put the import static clause.

Comment: Up with the imports. The documentation for the library that provides `text()` should have instructions.

Comment: You'll need to enclose the `xpath` in quotes, i.e. `driver.findElement(By.xpath("contains(text(), 'menu')"));`

Comment: I am getting this error now: The xpath expression 'contains(text(), 'menu')' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement.

Comment: @ayushibakshi Could you please provide some more input like Code of your page.

Answer (score 2):

`XPath` expressions need to be surrounded by quotes - and since the expression you are trying to parse also contains a string literal, I would suggest you switch the literal to single apostrophe `'`. Also, unless you expect the root element to contain the text `menu`, you'll need to be more specific about the element you are searching for. For example, the following xpath:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'menu')]"));
```

Will find the `li` element with the text "menu" (note xpath is case-sensitive):

```
<html>
    <foo>
        <bar>
            <ul>
                <li id="123">menu</li>
            </ul>
        </bar>
    </foo>
</html>
```

If possible, be even more certain, e.g. if you know that it is a `li` element:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'menu')]"));
```

**Edit**  (OP put the **actual** html up)

This will find the `DIV` element:

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//DIV[@style[contains(., 'm‌​enubar_menubutton.png')]]"));
```

Note that xpath is case sensitive - so you'll need to duplicate the SHOUTCASE tags.

Comment: I am getting this error 
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath == //*[contains(text(), 'menubutton')] (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)  by using both of these methods.

Comment: @ayushibakshi the data you are trying to match on is in the style **attribute** of a `DIV` element - i.e. no `text()` at all. Updated

Comment: So how do i reach this div element? It has no unique attribute to distinguish it.

Comment: You reach it with the xpath I gave you. Bcar made assumptions about  the html, probably relating to the random html I posted while waiting for you to provide us the real html :)

Comment: That xpath is picking any random thing as element, even the ones that do not exist. `"//DIV[@style[contains(., 'djsfhdjhfdjkfshf')]]"` this also doesn't throw any exception. The button doesn't click neverthless.

Answer (score 1):

i feel there is a much easier way to do this.

i'd personally just do:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.Id("123"))
```

or if you'd like to leverage css selectors you could do:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li:nth-child(1)"))  //baring you know the index of the list
```

Comment: Are you making up your own question, or just commenting on the answer by @StuartLC ?

Comment: The phone app didnt show whole post! Oops. I can delete that reply

Comment: The code doesn't say the id of the element. Here is the element -> `<DIV tabIndex=0 style="OVERFLOW: hidden; CURSOR: hand; HEIGHT: 22px; WIDTH: 60px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 10px; FILTER: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src=../images/style/default/menubar_menubutton.png, sizingMethod=scale); TOP: 5px"></DIV>`

Comment: Whats your code look like?  And what does the html look like. Posting things like it doesnt work makes it hard to help